# UICollectionViewCell Width same but Hight different for images

Tags: ios, swift, image, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am working on UICollectionview, in which UICollectionViewCell I want to display images that are available in Webservice. 
Now the thing is that these images have different hight and Width. I want to display images in UICollectionViewCell that automatically wrap its height according to image without leaving equal hight of cells.

This is very samilir to android view width :- match_parent and Height:- wrap_content.

Please refer images. Ideal Case and What i am getting.

Thanks in advance.

Image 1 Ideal Case [image]

Image 2 What i am Getting [image]

Comment: I Need this in UICollectionViewCell as it is clearly mention.

Comment: My bad,  I didn't read the question completely :(